# Programa que convierte de números romanos a arábigos siempre da Argumento no válido

Tags: array, c

Tengo este programa que pretende convertir de números romanos a arábigos y compila sin problemas  pero aunque le ingrese un número válido siempre sale por el default diciendo Argumento no válido.

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int main () {
   int numR = 0;
   int decR = 0;
   int cont = 0;
   int cont3R = 0;
   int numsR[15] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
   char letraR = ' ';
   char roman[15] = ""; 
   printf ("Ingrese un n£mero romano en el rango de I a MMMCMXCIX:\n");

   while ((letraR != 'n') && (cont < 15)) {
      letraR = toupper(getchar());
      switch (letraR) {
         /* V, L y D solo pueden aparecer una vez */
         case 'V': case 'L': case 'D':
            if ((cont > 0) && (roman[cont - 1] == letraR)) {
                  printf ("\nArgumento no v lido");
                  sleep(1000);
                  exit(0);
            }

            else { roman[cont++] = letraR; }
            break;

         case 'I': case 'X': case 'C': case 'M':
            if (cont3R <= 3) {
               roman[cont++] = letraR;
            }
            cont3R++;
            if ((cont3R > 3) && (roman[cont - 2] == letraR)) {
               printf ("\nArgumento no v lido");
               sleep(1000);
               exit(0);
            }
            if ((cont > 1) && ((cont3R > 3) || (roman[cont - 2] != letraR))) {
               cont3R = 1;
            }
            break;

         case 'n':   break;

         default:    printf("\nArgumento no v lido"); //<--- Sale por acá
                     sleep(1000);
                     exit(0);
     }
   }
```

Comment: Imprime el valor de letraR en el printf del caso default, y mira que te llega realmente. Podría ser que el getchar te devuelva la letra y un salto \n, y no entre en ninguna de las opciones...

Comment: Dale, lo pruebo y te digo.

Comment: No, aparece solo un espacio en blanco en la consola

Comment: En ese caso, vuelve a hacer la prueba pero quitando el toupper, y mira si te sigue devolviendo un espacio en blanco. Quizás estés teniendo problemas con esa con esa combinación. O prueba a utilizar scanf (solo para ver si te funciona el programa)

Comment: No. Ya lo resolví
en el while, estaba chquando la condición de que letraR != 'n' cuando tiene que que chequear si letraR != '\n' (salto de línea, faltaba una rerobarra.
Lo mismo en el default ('\n' en lugar de 'n')